# bcp command Incorrect syntax near '�'. Character is actually: "ä"

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, bcp, sql-server-2017

I have  **mssql-server** and **mssql-tools** installed on Ubuntu (Linux). When I try to export data with the **bcp** command using the following command-line:

```
bcp DBname.dbo.Täble_Name out Täble_Name -c -k  -S127.0.0.1 -Usa -PpassWord -r ~
```

I get this error:

> SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 102
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '�'.

The `�` is `ä`.

If I surround the `Täble_Name` with square-brackets:

```
 bcp DBname.dbo.[Täble_Name] out Täble_Name -c -k  -S127.0.0.1 -Usa -PpassWord -r ~
```

I get this error on the object name:

> SQLState = S0002, NativeError = 208
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'DBname.dbo.Täble_Name'.

I went further and added single-quotes `''` along with the `-q` option (which enables Quoted Identifiers):

```
bcp 'DBname.dbo.[Täble_Name]' out Täble_Name -c -k  -S127.0.0.1 -Usa -PpassWord -r ~ -q
```

The error becomes :

> SQLState = S0002, NativeError = 208
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'DBname.dbo.T�ble_Name'.

**NB: the command works perfectly with table names without this special character ä .**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that this is an encoding issue between the shell and **bcp** / SQL Server. SQL Server expects UTF-16 Little Endian, but Linux isn't using that. The default for my Linux VM is UTF-8 via `en_GB.UTF-8`.

**<TL;DR>** Use the "queryout" **bcp** command and specify `"SELECT * FROM ..."` instead of using the "out" command and simply supplying a table name.

What follows is my testing...

---

I got the list of available locales / encodings using:

```
$ locale -a
```

returned:

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
```

I tried several of those options by setting:

```
$ export LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8
```

and then trying again using:

```
$ export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```

Nothing seemed to make a difference. And each time I tried with various combinations of square brackets without `-q` and then with `-q`, and then no square brackets both with and without `-q`.

I even tried injecting the bytes that would equate to the UTF-16 LE character of `ä` via `$'\xe4\x00'` and even `$'\xe4'$'\x00'`, but no improvements.

**HOWEVER,**

what *did* work was changing the **bcp** command from `out` to instead be `queryout`, and then changing the table name to be part of a `SELECT` statement (I removed the `-r ~` switch only here to make the command line not scroll horizontally, but it was in my testing). I created the table in `[tempdb]` and ran the following:

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.[Täble_Name]" queryout tab -c -k -S127.0.0.1 -Usa -Ppass
```

No problems there. But interestingly enough, I changed the accented `ä` to a non-accented `a`:

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.[Table_Name]" queryout tab -c -k  -S127.0.0.1 -Usa -Ppass
```

and received the following error:

> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to resolve column level collations

That is an error from **bcp** and must be referring to the meta-data of `tempdb` since the only column in my test table uses the `INT` datatype.

Now, my instance-level Collation is accent-sensitive, so I wasn't really expecting the non-accented `a` to work (though I did expect an "invalid object" error). So, in order to test accent-insensitivity, I created a new Database with a Collation of `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_KS_WS_CS`, create that same table in the new DB, and added a few rows. I then ran the following two tests:

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM ImportTest.dbo.[Täble_Name]" queryout tab -c -k  -S127.0.0.1 -Usa -Ppass

bcp "SELECT * FROM ImportTest.dbo.[Table_Name]" queryout tab -c -k  -S127.0.0.1 -Usa -Ppass
```

and both worked!

Going back to the initial **bcp** command of just specifying the table name instead of a query, I was able to get `ImportTest.dbo.[Table_Name]` and `ImportTest.dbo.Table_Name` to work. However, I was still not able to get any combination of `ImportTest.dbo.[Täble_Name]` to work; all variations got the same errors as before.